# Can I setup my Sennheiser RS170 headphones to auto switch audio when turned off/on?

Tags: windows, audio, headphones

I'm using the on board audio on my [Asus P6T Deluxe V2](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1366/P6T_Deluxe_V2/) motherboard, green line-out goes to [Creative Labs](http://us.store.creative.com/Creative-GigaWorks-T20-Series-II-Speakers/M/B001RNOHDU.htm) speakers.  When I plug my Sennheiser RS170 headphones into the headphone jack of the speakers, the audio switches to the headphones as you would expect.  However, when I turned my headphones OFF, the audio doesn't switch back to the speakers unless I unplug them.

Is there software or other settings I can use to configure it to do what I want?  It's awfully annoying having to plug & unplug the headphones every time I want to use them.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no way for the computer to detect that the headphones are no longer receiving audio even though they're still plugged in. Unplug them.

Comment: Thanks, is there an more optimal way to set it up so the computer CAN detect it?  Through the use of a new sound card or something else?

Comment: Not really. I have a Bluetooth headset and my OS automatically detects when it turns on and routes all audio to it, but I don't have Windows.

Comment: This is basically a restriction of the hardware.  Some can do this, some can't.

Comment: None of them can. They detect presence of a plug within the jack, and the driver switches the outputs (or varies their volume).